# How to Disable components onClick of a Button in JSF?

Tags: jsf

In my application i have three buttons, If i click on one button I have to disable all the button till the operation on that button is finished.

I dont know how to disable the other two buttons. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to get the HTML element from the DOM and then set its `disabled` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('clientId').disabled = true;
```

Note that the `'clientId'` is the autogenerated HTML element ID. Rightclick page and *View Source* to find it out. If this contains prefixes like `j_id` and so on, then you need to give all parent [`UINamingContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) components like `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<f:subview>` and so on a fixed component ID, so that the client ID doesn't need to be autogenerated anymore.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But already gave all the Id to the buttons and the form,So i used them.